# create multiple react checkboxes from JS object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Object in state which stores the current value of four 'Risk Type' checkboxes

```
riskTypes: {"Fraud": true, "Steal": true, "Scam": true, "Theft": true},
```

on the subcomponent to render them I use:

```
Object.keys(this.props.riskTypes).forEach(key => {
          <li>
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value={key}  
                checked={this.props.riskTypes[key].value}
                onChange={this.handleRiskTypeChange}
              /> {key}
            </label>
          </li>
        })
      }
```

but this doesn't work, nothing is rendered, however if i console.log them instead of create checkboxes, it prints them fine. Any help much appreicated!

Comment: This evaluates to `undefined`. Instead you want to transform your list of types into a list of JSX elements. `.map` is used for 1-1 list transformations in JS. So `Object.entries(riskTypes).map(ele => {return <li>...</li>)}`

Comment: Can you share a little more of your code? Hard to see what's going on without seeing where you're setting state etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React expects JSX in some form, whether it's some HTML, or an array of HTML. `forEach` doesn't deliver that as it mutates the array rather than returning a new array.

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) to produce some JSX based on the information in state, and when you come to update the new state make sure that you keep the retain the old state properties.

I'm also using a `name` attribute on the input elements.

```js
const { Component } = React;

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      riskTypes: props.riskTypes,
      tempProp: 'temp',
      tempProp2: 'temp2'
    };
  }

  handleRiskTypeChange = (e) => {

    // Get the name of the input, and its checked value
    const { name, checked }  = e.target;

    // Because state is a nested object we
    // 1) need to keep the state
    // 2) update `riskTypes` using the existing
    // riskTypes values, and updating only the one we
    // need to update based on the name of the input
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      riskTypes: {
        ...this.state.riskTypes,
        [name]: checked
      }
    }, () => console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state)));
  }

  getRiskTypes = () => {
    const { riskTypes } = this.state;
    const entries = Object.entries(riskTypes);
    return entries.map(([key, value]) => {
      return (
        <li>
          <label>
            <input
              name={key}
              type="checkbox"
              value={key}
              checked={value}
              onChange={this.handleRiskTypeChange}
            />{key}
          </label>
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>{this.getRiskTypes()}</ul>
    );
  }

};

const riskTypes = {'Fraud': true, 'Steal': true, 'Scam': true, 'Theft': true };

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example riskTypes={riskTypes} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```